# Unable to populate multiple results for the invoice system using MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build an invoice generator GUI app using tkinter and reportlab. Currently, it's reading an excel file showing some results on treeview. However, to generate an invoice, I am creating a pdf file to show all the data for the invoice but unable to populate multiple results in the pdf file from MySQL table.

Here is my complete code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog
import mysql.connector
import os
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

def browse_file():
    # Open the file browser dialog
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    # Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel("mpo.xlsx", sheet_name='OrderDetails')
    df = df.fillna('NULL')

    # Connect to the MySQL database
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='magnetico')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Insert each row into the MySQL database
    for index, row in df.iterrows():

      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO perorder (mp_task_nr, batch_id, dropoff_sequence, id_user_payout_type, task_status, city, fleet, id_user, Name, Vendor, order_date, UID, KM, total_amount, Remarks) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", (row["mp_task_nr"], row["batch_id"], row["dropoff_sequence"], row["id_user_payout_type"], row["task_status"], row["city"], row["fleet"], row["id_user"], row["Name"], row["Vendor"], row["order_date"], row["UID"], row["KM"], row["total_amount"], row["Remarks"]))


    # Commit the changes and close the cursor and connection
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

def populate_treeview():
    # Connect to the MySQL database
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='magnetico')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    # Execute a SELECT statement
    cursor.execute("SELECT id_user, Vendor, KM FROM perorder")

    # Fetch the results
    results = cursor.fetchall()

    # Add the results to the Treeview widget
    for result in results:
        treeview.insert("", tk.END, values=result)

    # Close the cursor and connection
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

def generateInvoice():

  # Connect to the MySQL database
  conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', database='magnetico')
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  # Execute a SELECT statement to retrieve the invoice data
  cursor.execute("SELECT city, count(KM), total_amount, total_amount*count(KM), total_amount*count(KM), round(total_amount*count(KM)*0.05,2), total_amount*count(KM)*0.05+(total_amount*count(KM)) FROM perorder where city like '%XB' and KM between 1 and 3")

  # Fetch the results
  results = cursor.fetchall()

  # Create the PDF file
  pdf_file = "invoice.pdf"
  doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_file, pagesize=letter)

  # Create the table data
  table_data = []
  table_data.append(['City', 'Qantity', 'Rate', 'Amount', 'Taxable Value','Amount + 5% VAT', 'Grand Total'])
  for result in results:
    table_data.append([result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6]])

  # Create the table
  table = Table(table_data)

  # Set the table style
  table.setStyle(TableStyle([
      ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
      ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black)
  ]))

  # Build the document
  doc.build([table])


# Create the root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Megnatico Invoice System")
root.geometry("800x800")

# Create the treeview
treeview = ttk.Treeview(root)
treeview.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

treeview["columns"] = ("id_user", "Vendor", "KM")
treeview.column("id_user", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
treeview.column("Vendor", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
treeview.column("KM", width=150, minwidth=150, stretch=tk.NO)
treeview.heading("id_user", text="User ID")
treeview.heading("Vendor", text="Vendor")
treeview.heading("KM", text="KM")
treeview["displaycolumns"] = ("id_user", "Vendor", "KM")

# Create the buttons
read_excel_button = tk.Button(root, text="Read Excel", command=browse_file)
invoice_per_order_button = tk.Button(root, text="Invoice per Order", command=populate_treeview)
save_pdf_button = tk.Button(root, text="Generate Invoice", command=generateInvoice)
close_button = tk.Button(root, text="Close")

# Place the buttons in a frame and pack the frame to the right of the root window
button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(side="right", fill="both")
read_excel_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
invoice_per_order_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
save_pdf_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)
close_button.pack(padx=10, pady=5)


# Run the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

From the above code, the following code is populating invoice result:

```
# Execute a SELECT statement to retrieve the invoice data
cursor.execute("SELECT city, count(KM), total_amount, total_amount*count(KM), total_amount*count(KM), round(total_amount*count(KM)*0.05,2), total_amount*count(KM)*0.05+(total_amount*count(KM)) FROM perorder where city like '%XB' and KM between 1 and 3")
```

**Example of data I have**

[image]

There are multiple cities AUH, DXB but my current SQL query only generating for DXB. I need it should work for AUH and other KM values too such as 1 to 3, 4 to 5 and 6 to 7.

**Current Invoice Result**
[image]

**Example of an expected invoice**
[image]

If you have any further questions, please ask.

Comment: You need `GROUP BY City`

Comment: `total_amount` should be `SUM(total_amount)`. Otherwise you'll just get the amount from a random row in each group.

Comment: Where is `Product/Service Description` supposed to come from? That also needs to be in the grouping.

Comment: @Barmar currently, they are not in the database so I am just using city names as product/service description.

Comment: Why do you have `total_amount*count(KM)` twice in your query?

Comment: it's to show the user in the invoice that this going to be taxable value but we can remove it since there is already total amount field.